# How can you explain the structure of sentences beginning with "or"?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, sentence-structure, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

[image: Source]

Since most of you will ask for the source, I have uploaded an image containing the content itself. If needed, I can add the link to these texts also.

The sentences beginning with "or" confuse me a little. In the first context, does it mean, "**he wanted to walk on streets at least until he could see his daughter**"?

In the second context, if the first construction is talking about the possibility then the second should also. So, it should say **Or a beetle may get picked up..".** Doesn't the sentence sound strange with its current construction?

Comment: Your second example was written by a non-native English speaker and contains things such as _He crossbred garden pea plant having tallness trait with 
plant having dwarfness trait_ and _The gradual changes taking place in the organisms which in 
turn causing the diversity of the living organisms over the long 
period of time is called evolution._ You shouldn't be surprised if a sentence sounds strange. Be selective in your choice of teaching materials!

Answer (score 1):

In the first context, if Guy can't walk the streets forever, then he will walk them at least until he can see his daughter.

In the second context, the writer's intent is a Present Real Conditional, which uses "if" or "when". Since the writer conveyed a possibility with the modal verb "might" in the previous sentence, and used "or" to bridge the two sentences,  the "if" in this sentence is implied: "Or *if* a beetle is picked up..."

I agree that it would flow better if the writer had actually inserted the "if", or did as you suggested and wrote "Or a beetle *may get* picked up..." The word "may" is also a modal verb so it would match the previous sentence's structure.